# getting .mbox files from patchset(mails)

Tags: git, patch, mutt

I'm trying to find simple way to do git-am from mutiple PATCH mails.

so.. I wanna easily get .mbox files from a particular patchset(mails) to do git-am..

I've used mutt and changed patchset(mails) to .mbox like this blog

http://flavioleitner.blogspot.kr/2011/03/patch-workflow-with-mutt-and-git.html?view=magazine

But I have some problem when extracting .mbox files from patchset(mails).
(help me..)

I can get a .mbox file from only one mail(patch mail).
But I can't bring mutiple .mbox files from patchset(mails) at one go.

I just wonder other way getting .mbox files from patchset(mails)
to git-am into some branch on git system or another methods to do what I want.

Could I know the method about it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An mbox file is just a sequence of email messages. The dominant variant, the Berkeley mbox format, has a `From` (note significant trailing space, which apparently isn't rendered correctly at least in the Stack Overflow mobile view) separator before each message. But you don't normally create this format manually; selecting the messages in your mail client and copying or moving them to an mbox folder is definitely the easiest method, especially if you are new to email formats.

Comment: Thank you !! I misunderstood an .mbox file.I thought a mbox file contains only one patch mail but it isn't. OK I can seem to handle an mbox file that have multiple PATCH mails to do git-am !!